# Java program not producing correct result

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that takes a set of 10 numbers from the user, finds the smallest and largest value within the set, and displays it to the user. I kind of got the program to work but I am experiencing an issue. It looks like it skips through the first number and assigns the second number to be the smallest value. In class we haven't gotten to arrays yet so, I have to assume that the first value entered in the smallest and largest value Here's what I have:

```
   int smallestValue;
   int largestValue;
   int numInput;
   int counter = 1;
   int numSets = 0;

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
   System.out.print("Enter a set of 10 numbers: ");
   numInput = input.nextInt();
   smallestValue = input.nextInt();
   largestValue = input.nextInt();

   counter++;
        
   while (counter != 9)
   {

      numInput = input.nextInt();
      counter++;

      if (numInput > largestValue)
      {
         largestValue = numInput;
      }
                
      else if (numInput < smallestValue )
      {
          smallestValue = numInput;
      }

    }
        
        System.out.println( "Smallest is " + smallestValue ); 
        System.out.println("Largest is " + largestValue);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You call `input.nextInt()` 3 times before the loop so that is where the first values are going

Comment: I'm sorry. No, not yet. I'm only a few weeks into my course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *skips* value because you call `input.nextInt()` before the loop, you don't need to, and use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to initialize the min and max. Also when you iterate depending on a counter, it's commonly with a `for` loop

```
int numInput;
int smallestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int largestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);        
System.out.print("Enter a set of 10 numbers: ");
    
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    numInput = input.nextInt();

    if (numInput > largestValue){
        largestValue = numInput;
    }else if (numInput < smallestValue ){
         smallestValue = numInput;
    }
}
    
System.out.println( "Smallest is " + smallestValue ); 
System.out.println("Largest is " + largestValue);
```